# Database table not updating properly from PHP website code

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite, pdo

I am adding straw polls to a website using this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-web-poll-with-php--net-14257

I have modified this code so I can create my own polls by entering the poll title and questions which gets stored in a database table. This table is then queried and the polls are loaded from the database. This is working fine, however, when I am trying to return the number of votes for each question the value is coming back 0 every time. The table 'tally' holds the question id, answer id and number of votes.

When I try to insert data into this tally table from the webPoll class, both the QID and AID rows are blank, only the votes value increments each time.

My database is MySQL, the tutorial I followed was to insert data into an SQLite DB, I think this might be the problem but I can't seem to find a solution as of yet.

In summary, I need to get the insert statements in the webPoll class inserting QID, AID & votes values as QID and AID are not inserting.

**tally**

```
CREATE TABLE tally (
        QID varchar(32) NOT NULL,
        AID integer NOT NULL,
        votes integer NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (QID,AID))
```

**webPoll Class**

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "vote";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";


class webPoll {

# makes some things more readable later
const POLL = true;
const VOTES = false;

# number of pixels for 1% on display bars
public $scale = 2;


public $question = '';
public $answers = array();
private $header = '<form class="webPoll" method="post" action="%src%">
                   <input type="hidden" name="QID" value="%qid%" />
                   <h4>%question%</h4>
                   <fieldset><ul>';
private $center = '';
private $footer = "\n</ul></fieldset>%button%\n</form>\n";
private $button = '<p class="buttons"><button type="submit" class="vote">Vote!</button></p>';
private $md5 = '';

/**
 * ---
 * Takes an array containing the question and list of answers as an
 * argument. Creates the HTML for either the poll or the results depending
 * on if the user has already voted
 */
public function __construct($params) {
$this->question = array_shift($params);
$this->answers = $params;
$this->md5 = md5($this->question);  

$this->header = str_replace('%src%', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $this-  >header);
$this->header = str_replace('%qid%', $this->md5, $this->header);
$this->header = str_replace('%question%', $this->question, $this->header);

# seperate cookie for each individual poll
isset($_COOKIE[$this->md5]) ? $this->poll(self::VOTES) : $this- >poll(self::POLL);    
}
private function poll($show_poll) {
$replace = $show_poll ? $this->button : '';
$this->footer = str_replace('%button%', $replace, $this->footer);

# static function doesn't have access to instance variable
if(!$show_poll) {
    $results = webPoll::getData($this->md5);
    $votes = array_sum($results);
}

for( $x=0; $x<count($this->answers); $x++ ) {
    $this->center .= $show_poll ? $this->pollLine($x) : $this->voteLine($this->answers[$x],$results[$x],$votes);
}

echo $this->header, $this->center, $this->footer;
}
private function pollLine($x) {
isset($this->answers[$x+1]) ? $class = 'bordered' : $class = '';
return "
<li class='$class'>
        <label class='poll_active'>
        <input type='radio' name='AID' value='$x' />
            {$this->answers[$x]}
        </label>
</li>
";
}
private function voteLine($answer,$result,$votes) {
$result = isset($result) ? $result : 0;
$percent = round(($result/$votes)*100);
$width = $percent * $this->scale;
return "
<li>
        <div class='result' style='width:{$width}px;'>&nbsp;</div>    {$percent}%
        <label class='poll_results'>
            $answer
        </label>
</li>
";
}
/**
 * processes incoming votes. votes are identified in the database by a     combination
 * of the question's MD5 hash, and the answer # ( an int 0 or greater ).
 */
static function vote() {
if(!isset($_POST['QID']) ||
!isset($_POST['AID']) ||
isset($_COOKIE[$_POST['QID']])) {
    return;
}
try{
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vote', 'root', ''); 
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    }

try {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tally (QID,AID,votes) values ('QID',     'AID', '1')" );
    $sth->execute(array($_POST['QID'],$_POST['AID']));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    # 23000 error code means the key already exists, so UPDATE! 
    if($e->getCode() == 23000) {
        try {
            $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tally SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE     QID='$QID' AND AID='$AID'");
            $sth->execute(array($_POST['QID'],$_POST['AID']));
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            webPoll::db_error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    else {
        webPoll::db_error($e->getMessage());
    }
}

# entry in $_COOKIE to signify the user has voted, if he has
if($sth->rowCount() == 1) {
    setcookie($_POST['QID'], 1, time()+60*60*24*365);
    $_COOKIE[$_POST['QID']] = 1;
}
}
static function getData($question_id) {
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vote', 'root', ''); 
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    $STH = $dbh->prepare('SELECT AID, votes FROM tally WHERE QID = ?');
    $STH->execute(array($question_id));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    # Error getting data, just send empty data set
    webPoll::db_error($e->getMessage());
    return array(0); 
}

while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $results[$row['AID']] = $row['votes'];   
}

return $results;
}
/*
 * You can do something with the error message if you like. Email yourself
 * so you know something happened, or make an entry in a log
 */
static function db_error($error) {   
echo "A database error has occured. $error";
exit;
}   
}
```

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge in PHP here, but are placeholders the question marks? Also can you give me an example of where I have used them wrong please, that would be great, thank you

Comment: That has done the trick! Thank you very much for the answer and for the link chris85, very much appreciated :)
`$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tally (QID,AID,votes) values (?, ?, '1')" );
  $sth->bindParam(1, $QID);
  $sth->bindParam(2, $AID);
        $sth->execute(array($_POST['QID'],$_POST['AID']));`

Comment: I notice you are calling `new PDO()` inside the functions that use it. That may eventually cause you problems because it creates a new database connection for every function call. There are often limits on the number of connections allowed, and you'll suddenly see failures. Unless they require different connection credentials or databases, it is rarely necessary to use more than one connection. It's better to call `new PDO()` _once_ to create the object, then pass it as a parameter to functions needing it, like `WebPoll::vote($dbh)`

Comment: @Zeus7 I've moved my comments to the answer since it resolved the issue. I'd also look into creating one connection as suggested above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the prepared statements incorrectly. Inside the `values` you should have placeholders. The values in the `execute` are bound to those placeholders.

So:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tally (QID,AID,votes) values ('QID', 'AID', '1')" );
```

Is sending `QID`, and `AID` to your DB. If those are integer columns I suspect you'll get `0`s in their place.

You should change this to:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tally (QID,AID,votes) values (?, ?', '1')" );
```

Your `execute`:

```
$sth->execute(array($_POST['QID'],$_POST['AID']));
```

Is already set up correctly to pass the two values to the placeholders.

You also need to fix another `update` further down.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE tally SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE  QID=? AND AID= ?");
```

Prepared statements should rarely have variables in them and if they are in there they should have been checked against a whitelist of allowed terms.

You can read more about prepared statements:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Hi chris85, again, thank you very much. Is this the same for a delete statement also?

Comment: Yes, almost any SQL statement can be run with parameterized query, just might need to work with the formatting a bit. You can't bind columns or table names. For example in the prepare, `delete from table where name = ?` then in the execute as `execute(array('chris'))`.